# What does this JavaScript line actually do?

Tags: javascript

guys, I'm new to Javascript and I understand everything in this code through research, however, I don't understand what the [9] and [12] lines actually do to the code. My guess is that it calls id"msg" when the button is pressed but then what does that do? All help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>

<button onclick="RearrangeArray()">Rearrange Array</button>

<p id="msg"></p>



<script>

var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Computer","TV"];
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = products;

function RearrangeArray() {
    products.sort();
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = products;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right channel for this question. You'd be best off following a tutorial like the one here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: if you really don't know what this does, why you don't run this code and see the output?

Comment: I know how the code works, it rearranges the array, but what does calling the id"msg" and using .innerHTML and equalling to product do?

Comment: its inserting the array into DOM. It will get the msg id from DOM and will insert the array as his children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `<element id="msg"></element>`, and whatever is inside of it, erase and replace it with whatever is in the variable `products`, and parse out any HTML we find in it.

Answer (score 0):

It finds an element with Id of "msg" and set it's value to products, which is a reference to an array.

Basically document means [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_html_dom.htm).

getElementById is a function to locate an element in HTML.

You can understand innerHTML as element's content/value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Click the button to sort the array.</p>

// create a new button
// when a user clicks this button, call the RearrangeArray function
<button onclick="RearrangeArray()">Rearrange Array</button>

// create a new paragraph element and set its id to "msg"
// by doing so, you can get a reference to this element and modify the contents
// or attributes using javascript
<p id="msg"></p>


<script>

// define an array containing the following strings
var products = ["Printer", "Tablet", "Router", "Computer","TV"];

// get the paragraph element defined earlier, then set its innerHTML
// property to the products

// because products is not a string, it is coerced to a string by
// joining each of the elements with a comma
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = products;


// defines a function that is available globally
// the button above refers to this function in the 'onclick' handler
function RearrangeArray() {

    // sorts the array of products above using the javascript array sort function
    // the products should now look like this: ["Computer", "Printer", "Router", "TV", "Tablet"]
    products.sort();

    // get the element with the id of "msg" (which you defined above)
    // and set its html to the now-sorted array of products (coerced as a string)
    document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = products;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All HTML tag can have an `id` attribute and in a web page it should be unique, this is one of ways you can save a DOM Object of HTML tag in a variable using `the document.getElementById("ID_value")`. Also, the innerHTML property of a DOM Object store the HTML inside the proper tag of this Object.

So, this line:

```
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = products;
```

means that the values of the products array are storing as the plain HTML inside the tag that have the `msg` ID.